# iPhone Objective C KissXML XMLDocument String?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

I am creating an app for a friend of mine's podcast. The app has an rss xml file with its URL. After looking around on here, I decided to use KissXML for its documentation, but I can't seem to get the DDXMLDocument working correctly. I create a connection with the podcast's rss feed, with a URL of the form

```
NSString *podcastURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://podcast.website.com/rss/"];
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:podcastURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]
```

Then, in the delegate method

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

I am trying to use the received data to create the DDXMLDocument. I've tried initWithData and initWithString after creating the string with...

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I NSLog this string to see its contents, and it looks like a perfectly fine xml document to me. I create the XMLDoc with

```
DDXMLDocument *responseDoc = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:response options:0 error:&error];
```

But when I try to examine this new XMLDoc, all I get is NULL. 
Can anybody see if I'm doing anything wrong? The XML String response looks valid to me, but I suppose I don't really know. Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I figured I should add some of the XML I receive in case someone can find a problem with it that I cannot. The podcast has over 100 episodes, though, and each episode has all the stuff like the length, description, title, a bunch of stuff for iTunes, etc. Here's what the beginning of the XML looks like, and one of the episodes included (though not with any of the real podcast information):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"         xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<channel>
    <atom:link href="http://podcast.libsyn.com/rss/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
    <title>Podcast</title>
    <pubDate>Mon, 01 Oct 2012 06:18:33 +0000</pubDate>
    <lastBuildDate>Wed, 03 Oct 2012 22:19:37 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <generator>Libsyn WebEngine 2.0</generator>
    <link>http://podcast.libsyn.com</link>
    <language>en</language>
    <copyright><![CDATA[podcast]]></copyright>
    <docs>http://podcast.libsyn.com</docs>
    <managingEditor>person@hotmail.com (person@hotmail.com)</managingEditor>
    <description><![CDATA[Comedy podcast with People!]]></description>
    <image>
        <url>http://assets.libsyn.com/content/3220867.jpg</url>
        <title>podcast</title>
        <link><![CDATA[http://podcast.libsyn.com]]></link>
    </image>
    <itunes:author>Person1  and Person2</itunes:author>
<itunes:keywords>keywords</itunes:keywords>
<itunes:category text="Comedy"/>
    <itunes:image href="http://assets.libsyn.com/content/3220867.jpg" />
    <itunes:explicit>yes</itunes:explicit>
    <itunes:owner>
        <itunes:name><![CDATA[Person1]]></itunes:name>
        <itunes:email>person@hotmail.com</itunes:email>
    </itunes:owner>
    <itunes:summary><![CDATA[Show Summary]]></itunes:summary>
    <itunes:subtitle><![CDATA[podcast]]></itunes:subtitle>
            <item>
        <title>#123 - Episode123 Title</title>
        <pubDate>Mon, 01 Oct 2012 06:18:33 +0000</pubDate>
        <guid isPermaLink="false"><![CDATA[46f771dfb560aa4d573fe3ebdee86870]]></guid>
        <link><![CDATA[http://podcast.libsyn.com/Episode123_Title]]></link>
        <media:thumbnail url="http://assets.libsyn.com/item/2082832" />
        <description><![CDATA[<p>Description of Episode 123.</p>
<p>Music: Episode 123 Music</p>]]></description>
        <enclosure length="80069010" type="audio/mpeg" url="http://traffic.libsyn.com/podcast/123.mp3" />
        <itunes:duration>01:06:44</itunes:duration>
        <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
        <itunes:keywords />
        <itunes:subtitle><![CDATA[Episode 123 Description]]></itunes:subtitle>
                </item>
```

Sorry if this is too much to be posting here. Contained in this XML is the header stuff, and one item (episode). Does this look like correct code that should work with DDXMLDocument? Thanks again, everybody.

Comment: The only thing I see that looks questionable is your statement that you create this response string in the connection:didReceiveData method. This method will potentially be called multiple times, adding additional data with each call. You typically want to wait until all calls are completed and create the XML string the the connectionDidFinishLoading delegate method instead. However, given that you said that the string looks all right when you inspect it, I don't think that is the problem you are seeing. But you might want to make sure your not attempting to parse multiple times...

Comment: Ah gotcha, thanks for the response. I'm only just getting into learning connection things and I'm not super familiar with the delegate methods. I will try that, though, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like Tim Dean was correct in his comment. The XML Strings I was receiving were so huge that I didn't notice they were actually split up between times the NSLog was getting called in didReceiveData:. Everything was perfectly fine, the DDXMLDocument just couldn't be created with those partial strings. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe a bit late, but why won't you use [this example](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFKissXMLRequestOperation) from KissXML itself:

```
-(void)downloadXML{
    AFKissXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFKissXMLRequestOperation XMLDocumentRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://legalindexes.indoff.com/sitemap.xml"]] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {
      NSLog(@"XMLDocument: %@", XMLDocument);
  } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {
      NSLog(@"Failure!");
}];

[operation start];
```

Then all you need to do is take `XMLDocument` and pull out needed `DDXMLElements`